# Converting UTC to EST in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, timezone, nsdateformatter

I have a string of text in my application that conveys a time and the date, such as `let time = "2017-07-09T09:17:08+00:00"`. I want to take this string, which is in UTC, and convert it to a string that presents the time in EST. For my example, the resulting string would be `2017-07-09T05:17:08+00:00`. How can this be done?

I've tried using

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:time!)!
```

but printing the date gives me the same time in UTC.

Comment: Do you always want EST or do you want the user to see it in their own local time?

Comment: @rmaddy Local time would be preferred.

Comment: FYI - `2017-07-09T05:17:08+00:00` is not EST. That's still UTC, just an earlier time in UTC.

Comment: @rmaddy you're right -- my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to use a `DateFormatter` to convert your `Date` object into a `String`. By default, the date will be formatted to local time.

```
// First, get a Date from the String
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:time!)!

// Now, get a new string from the Date in the proper format for the user's locale
dateFormatter.dateFormat = nil
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long // set as desired
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium // set as desired
let local = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Note that there is no need to set any timezone for either set of code in this case.